# Big text file random access in C++

Tags: c++, text, file-io

I am writing some C++ functions for syntax analysis. The input is a potentially big text, and the output is a tree of substrings (long story short).
For now I've only used std::string as input, but the aim is to analyze text file.
My function is not a "one-pass" reading (saying it may frequently have to rewind and go back to previously read positions).

I'm asking myself if it would improve performances to copy all the file in a std::string, and then only read the string, or if there is no overhead using intensively std::basic_istream::seekg (I am not well aware of how a file is stored in RAM).

Could you give me a hint ?

Comment: How big will the files be? Megabytes? Gigabytes?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm asking myself if it would improve performances to copy all the
>   file in a std::string, and then only read the string,

Yes.

Comment: strings are allocated on contiguous memory block, ropes (segmented model) will be much better.

Comment: @Sarang Depends on the input data size. Up to a few megabytes? Use a contiguous block. Beyond that, a rope may be beneficial. For very big data you’d do neither and use memory-mapped files.

Comment: Yes I agree, it all depends the size of the file.

Comment: ok, thank you all.I don't think the files will ever be more than 50 megabytes, so I guess I should use std::strings